# Way to know if SAP WAS server is ABAP, Java or integrated

Tags: java, abap, application-server, netweaver

Using transaction `SM51`, I get a list of servers in my system (there is only one).  It has the following information:

- Server Name
- Host Name
- Message Types (Having value Dialog Batch Update Upd2 Spool Enqueue ICM VMC)
- Server Status (Active)

Then if I double click on this a list of processes of various types (DIA, UPD, ENQ, BGD, SPO, UP2)

My question is for this server, is there a way to know if this application server is of type ABAP, Java or integrated?

Comment: If you see these processes, you can be sure to have an ABAP application server. I'm not sure whether Java servers would show up in SM51 at all, so I won't attempt to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks.  But would you know how I can check whether I have a Java server at all, not necessarily via SM51 but some other transaction maybe?

Comment: do you have os,http,file system , sap mmc access to theese systems?

Answer (score 1):

The SAP application server, WAS, runs a java process and technically is a java server.

Answer (score 1):

Only ABAP and ABAP+Java (dual stack) systems can be accessed via SAPGUI - if you're accessing a system using SAPGUI, it must, by definition, be either ABAP or ABAP+Java.

There are a few places in the ABAP stack you can check to see if you're using a dual stack system:

1. `SM51` - On dual stack systems you'll see **J2EE** amongst the *Message Types* (see image below, taken from a NetWeaver PI 7.1 dual stack system). Purely ABAP systems won't have it listed.

   [image: SM51 on dual stack system]
2. `SMICM` - Check the list of services in transaction `SMICM` (menu: *Goto --> Services*) - dual stack systems will have the J2EE services listed too (look for P4 and IIOP in particular). There will also be an *AS Java* menu in `SMICM` on ABAP+Java systems.
3. Profile parameters - ABAP+Java systems will have J2EE-specific parameters in their start/instance profiles (for example, `rdisp/j2ee_start`).